# How do I name this single-class dependency inversion package that contains an interface

Tags: java, oop, naming-conventions, package

I am reading https://books.google.bg/books/about/Agile_Software_Development.html?id=0HYhAQAAIAAJ&hl=en and there is a chapter about packages and how to group classes in them, how to maintain cohesion, stability, responsibility, independence etc.

In my application I want to keep the JSON converter at the periphery of the architecture. I want to have an interface class, something like this:

```
public interface JsonConverter {

    InputStream fromJsonObject(JSONObject jsonObject);
    InputStream fromJsonArray(JSONArray jsonArray);
    JSONObject toJsonObject(OutputStream outputStream);
    JSONArray toJsonArray(OutputStream outputStream);

}
```

and I want another package to contain the implementation of this interface - some library that I will be able to easily swap out for something different.

Here is a picture from the book that explains this:

[image]

And here is a picture of the explanation of the techinique:

[image]

My problem is the following: **How do I name the package that contains the interface and the json converter library package?**

First of all I hate Hungarian notations so I dont want to call it something that starts with I. Second of all, I cannot think of a name that does not include more than one word in it, and I don't know whether I should use camelCase or dots between words or none.

Can I name the packages:

```
my.app.json.interface
my.app.json.converter
```

EDIT: Looks like I cannot use `interface` as a part of a package name, so I still don't know how to name my packages

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public interface Converter<X,Y> {

    InputStream fromObject(X object);

    InputStream fromArray(Y array);

    X toObject(OutputStream outputStream);

    Y toArray(OutputStream outputStream);
}

public class JsonConverter implements Converter<JSONObject,JSONArray> {

    @Override
    public InputStream fromObject(JSONObject object) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream fromArray(JSONArray array) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public JSONObject toObject(OutputStream outputStream) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public JSONArray toArray(OutputStream outputStream) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

The reason you are abstracting out the interface is so that you can replace it later with something else. You must therefore move all of the `JSON` stuff into the implementatiuon and all of the callables into the interface. Generics is a neat way of parameterising the result to retain type safety.

Comment: Not looking for something like this, I need to find a good name for the package. The interface I posted is supposed to be final. Then in the converter package, there will be a library - jackson, gson, whatever, there will be a class there that will implement this interface I posted. Then, in some other package where I need json conversion, I will pass a JsonConverter type class

Comment: BTW Good idea for the generics!

Comment: So basically, just looking for a good name for the package that will only contain this interface class and nothing else in it.